# Access iCloud photostream on Ubuntu

Tags: apple

My friend shared a photostream via iCloud with me. Unfortunately, I can't sign up to iCloud because I don't have any apple devices and the icloud control panel for windows doesn't work on ubuntu.

Is there any work-around to access the photos at least via web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Ask your friend for the web address and enter it into Firefox. You can browse pictures online that way, but only if the folder your in allows you to (e.g. public website or your apple id).